# XSLT Match Elements and Populate

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to match an element in one node with an element in another node and pull that other element into my resulting XML.  Here is my source:

```
<Nodes>
    <Metadata>
        <ItemDefinition id="123456" name="Box 1" />
        <ItemDefinition id="234567" name="Box 2" />
        <ItemDefinition id="345678" name="Box 3" />
    </Metadata>
    <Node>
        <Item id="123456" type="1">Test</Item>
        <Item id="234567" type="4">Green</Item>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <Item id="123456" type="1">Test 2</Item>
        <Item id="234567" type="4">Yellow</Item>
        <Item id="345678" type="4">Red</Item>
    </Node>
</Nodes>
```

Here is my desired output:

```
<Node>
    <Name>Box 2</Name>
    <Name>Green</Name>
</Node>
<Node>
    <Name>Box 2</Name>
    <Name>Yellow</Name>
</Node>
<Node>
    <Name>Box 3</Name>
    <Name>Red</Name>
</Node>
```

So I'm trying to match that "id" element for every Item with a "type" of 4 and pull back the name of that field into individual nodes.  There will always be that Metadata node, but the number of "Node"s after that will vary, as will the number of "Item"s and "ItemDefinition"s.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problems is best solved with the use of a **key**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="meta" match="ItemDefinition" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<output>
    <xsl:for-each select="Nodes/Node/Item[@type=4]">
        <Node>
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="key('meta', @id)/@name"/></Name>
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="."/></Name>
        </Node>
    </xsl:for-each>
</output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I have added a root `<output>` element to the result, otherwise it would not be a well-formed XML document.